# Find the distribution function of $Y=aX+b$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> A random variable $X$ has distribution function $F$. What is the distribution function of $Y=aX+b$ where $a,b$ are real values?

There are three cases to consider, they are $a>0,a<0$ and $a=0$ because we need to change $x=(y-b)/a$. When $a=0$, the distribution function of $Y$ is $1$ if $b\leq y$ and $0$ if $b>y$. When $a>0$, I would have $\mathbb{P}(X\leq (y-b)/a)=F((y-b)/a)$. But I don't know how to calculate the case $a<0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the distribution function of $Y$ be $F'$. Since you have solved the case $a \geq 0$, we focus on the case $a < 0$ below. We have:
\begin{align}
\Pr(Y \leq y) =&~\Pr(aX + b \leq y) = \Pr(aX \leq y - b) = \Pr(X \geq \frac{y-b}{a}) \\
=&~1 -F(\frac{y-b}{a}) + \Pr(X = \frac{y-b}{a})
\end{align}
because $1 - F(\frac{y - b}{a}) = \Pr(X > \frac{y - b}{a})$.